# Synology DS120j autostart node.js server in deamon mode on system boot

Tags: node.js, service, boot, autostart, synology

How to start node.js server in deamon mode on Synology DS120j NAS (and other synology models if it's similar) drive since it looks that there is not systemd?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an installer package (spk).
Therefore you find related developer documents provided [by synology](https://www.synology.com/de-de/support/developer#tool)

If you have docker on your diskstation, you find a solution [by KeesCBakker on github](https://github.com/KeesCBakker/synology-ci-cd-nodejs-demo)

Even it is possible to create the required files inplace on the DiskStation, I recommend to create an spk with a build environment as provided by [SynoCommunity](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc)